# でしょう/だろう vs しようかな for "I guess I'll..."

Tags: meaning, word-choice, usage

I'm trying to write the phrase, "I guess I'll unpack tomorrow." And I can't decide between だろう or かな for the "I guess"

Here's what I got.

明日、荷解きするだろう。

明日、荷解きしようかな。

I'm leaning toward the latter, but I'm not terribly sure.

Comment: Using するだろう for your own actions, when you have full control over them, sounds weirdly impersonal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「明日、荷解きするだろう」 is more like "It looks like I'll be unpacking tomorrow". This sounds like you have no direct control over what you're doing tomorow. If you had a disease that causes you to lose your memory every night, wrote down in your journal "Unpack the case" to tomorrow's self, and said "(Okay, this way,) I guess I'll unpack it tomorrow", then this could be 荷解きするだろう. Otherwise, you almost never have to say something like this referring to yourself.

「明日、荷解きしようかな」 is a natural sentence, but this sounds like the chance of doing 荷解き tomorrow is 60% or so (かな is like "..., maybe?"). If you're relatively certain about the plan, just saying 荷解きしよう may be enough.

Comment: So just saying しよう adds more certainty than しようかな? That makes sense. I never learned the volitional form in that context. I always thought of it as either "Let's..." or "I think..." as in しようと思う.